# How to turn on my iPad Air 2

Tags: ios, ipad

Last night I left my iPad close to my bed, placed above my Windows phone 8. When I woke up in the morning I was first surprised that the alarm didn't work, but when I checked, the iPad was off and very hot the side of the battery, the Microsoft phone was also very hot on its screen but the phone was on and is working properly but my iPad took some minutes to cool down and up to now it doesn't switch on.

What is the step to power on or reset the power button on an iPad when one press doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try connecting it to the charger? The battery may have run out of charge. Leave it plugged in to the charger for half an hour and then try turning it on again.

It's recommended to follow the steps outlined in this Apple support document, [If your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch won‘t turn on or is frozen](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201412).

The last resort would be to get in touch with [Apple Support](https://getsupport.apple.com) or get it inspected by an authorised Apple technician.